# Meteor.js: Find all documents and return in reverse natural order

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to return all documents in a collection, to use it with an {{#each}} in my template. My code looks like this:

`return Answers.find({}, {sort: {$natural:-1}})`

But the documents are returned in natural order (not reverse). Does anyone know why? I got the $natural selector from the MongoDB documentation, so I don't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Can't tell why don't it returns in reverse order.

But you can create an array in the template helper method and return reverse of an array using `array.sort()` or `array.reverse()` functions.

For ex: Say you `Answers` collection looks like this:

```
Answers({ansNo: 1, ansBody: "body1"},
        {ansNo: 2, ansBody: "body2"},
        {ansNo: 3, ansBody: "body3"});
```

And the array to be returned is:

```
var AnswersArr = new Array();
```

then in your template helper :->

```
var tempCollection = Answers.find({});
tempCollection.forEach(function(data){
    var obj = {ansNo: data.asnNo, ansBody: data.ansBody};
    AnswersArr.push(abj);
});

AnswersArr.sort(function(a, b){return b.ansNo - a.ansNo;});  //sort in reverse order

return AnswersArr;
```

Comment: Thanks, my question was why the natural order sort does not work, because I think it will be faster to do it with a cursor. But your answer was still useful, as I will do it that way until I figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect Meteor still doesnt have support for advance Mongo queries. I have same problem with cursors next() and hasNext() methods.

Answer (score 2):

**Sort** isn't a parameter but a separate function to be called after **find()** on the resulting **Cursor** object. This is the method that the MongoDB documentation is referring to and works with drivers such as MongoJS:

```
return Answers.find().sort({$natural: -1});
```

It seems Meteor hasn't added the **sort()** function to their implementation of **Cursor**, so an alternate solution would be to sort by the **_id** field which is generated based on date (and hence insertion order):

```
return Answers.find({}, {sort: {'_id': -1}});
```

Comment: find() returns a Cursor. I can not see that Cursor has a sort() function: [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor). Do  you mean .fetch() and then sort()?

Comment: Mongo does have a sort() on Cursor - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort - but I guess Meteor's driver doesn't implement it for some reason. I'll modify my answer to offer an alternate solution.

Comment: Sort by ID will not work! The ID (if it is autogenerated) is a hash based on whatever :) So you can't sort by it :\

Comment: Incorrect. _id is not a hash and it's generated based on a number of factors (the first 4 bytes of which are the insertion time - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) so sorting based on _id will be accurate to a 1 second precision.

Comment: This didn't work for me, natural order was not at all the same as sorting by _id in my case.  I'm guessing this is due to updates to Meteor since this was posted.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could do this:

```
return Answers.find().fetch().reverse();
```

I know it would be nicer to do it via the sort parameter, but I don't think it's possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you **might** be confusing definitions of 'natural order' here. One the one hand there is a natural sort order for letters/strings (A,B,C...) and numbers (1,2,3...).

But in the case of mongo, 'natural' refers to the order the data was written to disk. '{$natural:1}' returns 'documents in the order they exist on disk...' and, so '{$natural:-1}' reverses that (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/).

So without the code that writes the data and some insight into how it was written to disk, we cannot test your hypothesis that it is not working correctly.

Comment: despite the use of the term in the documentation, '... exist on disk' may be overly specific...it is really a logical order, from what I can see.