# Meteor: How do you roll data thru a table?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, reactive-programming

If I'm doing a `find()` and returning the last five records why aren't all five records updated when `{{# each}}` is updated? Isn't the `find()` triggered to return the last 5 records?

Basically, I'm just trying to roll my data through the table as an item is added, so if items 1 thru 5 displayed in the table and you add an item, the table will display item 2 thru 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'limit' and 'sort' ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers)):

```
{{#each something}}
    <tr>
      ....
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Then your find, make sure you specify 'sort' since you need to tell meteor how it needs to 'roll' them, i.e by date? (this example assumes you have a `date` field):

```
Template.yourtemplate.helpers({
    something: function() {
        return YourCollection.find({}, {limit: 5, sort:{date:-1}})
    }
});
```

The `-1` is the sorting order, the higher (or later) dates come up at the top, if you use `1` the earliest come up at the top.

Comment: This returns correctly, but it doesn't update the table (view). If I have rows 1,2,3,4,5 in a table, and then I insert 6, it doesn't remove row 1 data and move everything up so it displays 2,3,4,5,6. 
I can manually remove a row, and 6 will appear, but .insert() doesn't change the view.

Comment: @AaronSpesard It should remove the row in the way you describe, make sure you've used it correctly and linked up the helpers properly including use the correct sort specifier. When inserting keep in mind you need a sort specifier. Mongo/Meteor need to know how to arrange it, is it by date, alphabetical order of something in it, etc? It wouldn't implicitly know where it should make an order from just like that

Comment: It wasn't. I had to manually delete the rows to see the data. The code is here: https://github.com/aaronspe/ChubTrak.git

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using Justin McCandless' answer from this thread where the sort wasn't working at all.

[Meteor.js: Find all documents and return in reverse natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554101/meteor-js-find-all-documents-and-return-in-reverse-natural-order)

```
return WeighIn.find({}, {sort:{weight: -1}, limit:5}).fetch().reverse();
```

Adding the reverse() made the table behave the way I needed it to.