# How to sort collection's nested array descending in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a Nodes collection that looks like: http://codepaste.net/kttsj1.

I want to retrieve that collection and have the data field's array sorted in reverse order or by outputTime ascending. Then, I want to have just the first 10 results (got this to work with $slice).

How could I achieve this?

Thanks,

Jori

Comment: I'm not familiar with meteor but have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554101/meteor-js-find-all-documents-and-return-in-reverse-natural-order it seems like that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem!

I simply gave the nested data array its own collection called SensorData and linked that to the nodes collection with an id.

Now in a Meteor method I can SensorData.find({nodeId: id}, {sort: {outputTime: -1}, limit 10});.

I have to do it in a method though, because it seems that client side does not support this query. (Probably the sort or limit thats not supported)

Thanks for the help to everyone who responded :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
YourCollection.find({},{sort:{name:-1}}); //for descending order

YourCollection.find({},{sort:{name:1}}); //for ascending order
```

and if you want to limit the number of results:

```
YourCollection.find({},{sort:{name:-1},{limit: 10}});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: There is no `$sort` for meteor Collections, and add a `limit: 10` to limit your results in your answer

Comment: The thing is, I want the 10 last added items to an inner array. I have a field named 'data' which is an array of object and I want the last 10 one of those, which are located at the bottom of the dataset, so I would have to order by desc. to grab those 10 from that particular field. The limit just grabs a maximum of 10 documents of that particular collection, right?

Comment: I see, can you show a reference of what you have done so far? So we can further help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If it is robomongo:

```
YourCollection.find({},{sort:{"data.outputTime":1}}).limit(10);
```

If it is JS:

```
YourCollection.find({},{sort:{"data.outputTime":1},limit:10});
```